# Spring handle "invalid character found" error

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, http-headers, httprequest

I programmed a website with Spring and everything works fine.
But when I run the website on my server where everyone has access to then sometimes I get a weird error message and I think that someone tries to hack my website.

```
2022-11-17 13:44:28.935  INFO 17736 --- [nio-9000-exec-3] o.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor   : Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in method name [0x160x030x010x000xee0x010x000x000xea0x030x030xfa!"0xbe,0x14`0x860xc00x0e0xd2k0xed0x840x100xb6;0xc84?zh0x1by0xc6y0x7fiz(0xa2= ]. HTTP method names must be tokens
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:419) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:271) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

I think this because when I run the website on my local computer I don't get such messages and on my local computer I am the only one that has access to the website.

If someone tries to hack me I don't really care because as you can see in the error message it is not working.
But the error message is annoying so does someone know how/where to handle the exception?